# iPod cannot connect

Tags: ipod-touch

A pop up on my iPod 4th gen said blue skag could not connect, which freaked me out. I pressed cancel and turned off the Wi-Fi to see if I could find anything in the settings to help.

This has happened in the past but I completely reset my iPod so this shouldn't be happening. I don't know if this is a virus or an official thing. Please help.

Blue Skag is not my Wi-Fi's or iPod's name.

Comment: I'm assuming "blue skag" is the name of your iPod? Or the name of your Wi-Fi network?

Comment: @AceRedstone You always have enough reputation to comment on your own questions. The problem is you tried to comment with a different account than you asked the question with. I suggest merging the accounts using the Contact Us link in the footer.